# Java GUI JSlider

Tags: java

I just started using java :).

My problem is:

I want to make a GUI with a JSlider and then that slider moves I want a number in JTextField to change.
I tried a lot stuff, but I always get an error.

I always get an an error if I try to update GUI information, but I do not get an error if I use System.out.println to print changed value of slider. Why is that?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER = new JSlider(0, 10000, 0);
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.setLocation(150, 375);
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.setSize(450,50);
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.setMajorTickSpacing(2500);
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.setMinorTickSpacing(250);
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.setPaintTicks(true);
ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.setPaintLabels(true);
PANE.add(ATSTUMAS_SLIDER);



ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){ 
   @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
   { 
      if (ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.getValueIsAdjusting()){ 
        int a = ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.getValue(); 
        ATSTUMAS_COUNTER = new JTextField(String.valueOf(a));
      } 
   } 
});


ATSTUMAS_COUNTER.setLocation(640, 385);
ATSTUMAS_COUNTER.setSize(40, 25);
ATSTUMAS_COUNTER.setEditable(false);
PANE.add(ATSTUMAS_COUNTER);
```

Comment: An advice, in Java code conventions says  variables start with lower case, classes starts with upper case, and methods statrs with lower case, always with camelcase style.

Comment: And it's advisable to use an appropriate layout manager

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you stop creating new ATSTUMAS_COUNTER instances, and just update the text value?

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
  Document doc = ATSTUMAS_COUNTER.getDocument();
  doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
  doc.insert(0, String.valueOf(ATSTUMAS_SLIDER.getValue()), null); 
}
```

Also, only update on an "isAdjusting" method if it is important to have the value redraw before the person stops moving the slider around.

Comment: Why not just use JTextField#setText?

Comment: Good point, except that when I glanced at the javadoc, I must have missed it, even to the point that I needed to dig through the document details.